# React-Native app error while trying to install it in xiaomi redmi 9t, doesn't show any dialog box to permit allowing app install

Tags: react-native

- What went wrong:
  Execution failed for task :`app:installDebug`.

  ```
     com.android.builder.testing.api.DeviceException: 
     com.android.ddmlib.InstallException: 
     INSTALL_FAILED_USER_RESTRICTED:Install canceled by user
  ```

Comment: Give access to install app in your mobile, setting -> developer options

Answer (score 0):

In your mobile device, make sure you have enabled the following buttons.

Settings > Additional Settings > Developer options

Turn ON Developer Options

Turn ON USB Debugging

Turn OFF MIUI optimization

Turn ON Install via USB